# python script works interactively but fails with pandas write permission problems as a cron job

Tags: pandas, permissions

I have Anaconda with python 3.8 on macOS Big Sur. The python script works just fine within PyCharm or interactively inside a shell script :

*/Users/nicholaskalita/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.8 /Users/nicholaskalita/PycharmProjects/CrpytoScrape/CMCScrape.py*

The shell script need to be launched regularly, which is where the trouble begins. *launchd* starts it (crontab doesn't seem to work on MacOs but that's another story) as root but the python script fails with

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/nicholaskalita/PycharmProjects/CrpytoScrape/CMCScrape.py", line 241, in 
dframe.to_csv(FilePath+NQuotes, index=False)
File "/Users/nicholaskalita/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3170, in to_csv
formatter.save()
File "/Users/nicholaskalita/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 185, in save
f, handles = get_handle(
File "/Users/nicholaskalita/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 493, in get_handle
f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, errors=errors, newline="")
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/local/ ...*

The destination directory happens to be on network drive but neither applying *chmod 777* to it nor moving to a local disk solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After clearing out the following directories this problem vanished

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/StartupItems
```